# Flexible tube for threading through transparent round bricks

Tags: design

I'm planning on doing a replica of the Belaggio fountains. I can't find it now, but I remember somewhere I saw someone do a build where they threaded a transparent tube through some 1 x 1 round bricks to make a "bendy" transparent column. I'd like to use this technique to make some moving fountain sprays.  Does anyone know anything about such a technique, and what parts I need?

Comment: Please send a link to that build whenever you have time.

Answer (score 4):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you'll need 1x1 round bricks and something bar-sized and flexible to hold them together.

Alex pointed out that the hoses typically used for this sort of thing aren't available in trans-clear. Pneumatic tubing has been produced in trans-clear, so it could be an option, but you'd need a different design, as pneumatic tubing will not fit through an open stud.

You could use [fiber optic cable](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=x400c25&idColor=12#T=S&C=12&O=%7B%22color%22:12,%22iconly%22:0%7D):

[image: Fiber optic cable]

I tried stringing some transparent 1x1 round bricks on it, and I think it creates the look that you are going for:

[image]

Comment: The item provided in your URL seems to be a different part as its diameter for most of the length is significantly smaller than of the one pictured below URL.

Comment: @Alex Good point. I've fixed the link.

Answer (score 0):

The technique you are referring to utilise parts in [Hose, Rigid 3mm D.](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogList.asp?catType=P&catString=528) category. Despite the name they are somewhat flexible and can be bent (this is also how LEGO use them in some sets). Diameter of these hoses is equal to 3.18mm, which is, coincidentally, the diameter of inner hole you can find in studs. Including the 1x1 round brick you've mentioned. These hoses also work with Technic elements that have a cross holes for axles as well as some pins.

Unfortunately, none of these hoses have been produced in Tran-Clear color. So you either have seen a hose in different color or some 3rd-party hose compatible with LEGO.

Comment: Thanks Alex, if I know the size I need, I'll check with the hardware store to see if they have something that will work.